# jest-each tear down is not called

Tags: jestjs

I am trying use `beforeEach` and `afterEach` for test.each, seems these set up and tear down are not called, here is my sample code

```
let mydata;

describe('test each feature of jest %re', () => {

    beforeAll( () => {
        return mydata = [1,2,5,7] ;
    });

    dataArr = [1,2];
    it.each(dataArr)

        ('%i', async(data) => {
            expect(data).toBe(1);

        });
});
```

I'm getting error
 ● test each feature of jest %re › encountered a declaration exception